# wpa_cli events output to file

Tags: wifi-direct, wifip2p, wpa-supplicant

I have requirement to write wifi p2p application. So I am trying to use wpa_cli commands.
I want to write wpa_cli event output to one file. So to handle errors and success events

I had referred this link for testing wifi direct -
https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/digidocs/embedded/dey/2.6/cc8x/bsp_r_wifi-direct.html

Can anyone tell me , how it can be done

I tried directing to one file but output of wpa_cli command is not going inside it

Regards,
Deeksha